# C# Внесение изменений в xml файл из txt файла

Tags: c#, массивы, xml, текст, datatable

Есть два файла:
Файл txt(файл источник), в котором 4 колонки и несколько строк
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Другой файл(файл в котором нужно сделать апдейт строк), формата xml.
Вот часть кода xml файла который нужно заменить данными из текстовика.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Суть что бы заменить:
 ConnectionManagaerID = "2й столбец txt"
 ConnectionManagaerID = "1й столбец txt"

не могу реализовать это обновление.
Пробовал с помощью массива, создание DataTable.

Comment: Постройте программу на базе XmlReader  -> XmlWriter, например. Или загрузите xml, выгрузите xml извесным для вас способом, что б разговор был более предметным. DataTable не подходит, потому что он позволяет редактировать только секцию "данные".

Comment: Можно прочесть в текст - и просто заменить в тексте.

Comment: Ок, DataTable отбрасываем. Как в C#  по условию(ключу) сравнивается два файла?Я последовательно не могу прописать это. Что бы найти в интернете отдельные конструкции решения вопроса.

Comment: Можно так: `А[i] == B[i]` предварительно в А и B считав файлы.

Comment: Попробуйте по частям: 1) считать первый файл 2) считать второй файл 3) внести изменения 4) переписать файл. Сейчас у Вас слишком много шагов для одного вопроса.

Comment: Данные для замены берутся из первого и второго столбца, это понятно. А из какой строки? Ведь их же там несколько.

Comment: В файле txt хранится количество уникальных соединений. И когда сравниваем два файла то условием будет ConnectionManagaerID для кадого соединения. т.е. каждая трока это отдельный конекшн.

Answer (score 1):

Имеем такой текстовой файл с таким содержимым

> Package.ConnectionManagers[xxx]|{XXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX}|Data Source=YYY; User ID=fjfjf;|ACS Available Moths.dts

Имеем такой файл XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<connections>
  <connection refId="PackageId..." connectionManagerID="conManagerId..." connectionManagerRefId="conManRefId..." description="des..." name="OleDbConnection..." />
</connections>
```

После имеем такой файл

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<connections>
   <connection refId="PackageId..." connectionManagerID="{XXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX}" connectionManagerRefId="Package.ConnectionManagers[xxx]" description="des..." name="OleDbConnection..." />
</connections>
```

Вот код программы целиком, можете экспериментировать

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string xmlFile = @"D:\cons.xml";
        string txtFile = @"D:\cons.txt";
        //MakeXML(xmlFile);

        ChangeConnectionAttributes(xmlFile, txtFile);
    }

    private static void MakeXML(string xmlFile)
    {
        XDocument doc = new XDocument();
        XElement elm = new XElement("connections",
                            new XElement("connection", 
                                new XAttribute("refId", "PackageId..."),
                                new XAttribute("connectionManagerID", "conManagerId..."),
                                new XAttribute("connectionManagerRefId", "conManRefId..."),
                                new XAttribute("description", "des..."),
                                new XAttribute("name", "OleDbConnection...")));

        doc.Add(elm);
        doc.Save(xmlFile);
    }

    private static void ChangeConnectionAttributes(string xmlFile, string txtFile)
    {
        var strs = File
                      .ReadAllText(txtFile)
                      .Split(new[] { '|' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(xmlFile);

        var c1 = doc.Descendants("connection")
                    .First()
                    .Attributes()
                    .First(a => a.Name == "connectionManagerID").Value = strs[1];

        var c2 = doc.Descendants("connection")
                    .First()
                    .Attributes()
                    .First(a => a.Name == "connectionManagerRefId").Value = strs[0];

        doc.Save(xmlFile);
    }

}
```

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov ну, да чтоб отработали запросы. ОК, можно как у вас.

Comment: Я так понимаю в txtFile и xmlFile, должны быть пути к файлам. Но у меня не отрабатывает.

Comment: @Andrey, вам надо в отладке пройтись, и посмотреть что не так. Я код писал с реальными файлами в таком же формате как у вас на картинках, код проверен, он рабочий. Или приложите реальное содержимое в текстовом виде, а не в голимых картинках, чтоб я мог сам проверить.

Comment: Проверил. код рабочий- обновляет. Возможно этой мой косяк в описании, обновление происходит не по необходимой логике.

Comment: @Andrey что значит: "...обновление происходит не по необходимой логике."? Конкретнее, что не так? Оно ведь как вам нужно, а не мне, почему я должен из вас вытягивать нужную инфо?

Comment: Я же не знаю, намерны вы помочь в полной мере или первого сольюшена достаточно, а дальше сам). В общем условием обновления является: первый столбец txt файла(Package.ConnectionManagers[*****]) = знечению connectionManagerRefId(xml файла) ---> заменить ConnectionManagerID на {C70A130D-E303-4456-9269-73858EBB029E}

Comment: @Andrey я изменил ответ, читайте внимательно.

Comment: @Bulson, спасибо, скрипт работает)